# Why the performance of cuda kernel w/i divergence is better than w/o divergence?

Tags: cuda

Hi I am writing cuda kernel to understand the behavior of warp divergence.
These are 3 kernels I have:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "util.h"
#include <chrono>

__global__ void wardUp(float *c)
{
    float a = 0.0;
    float b = 0.0;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if ((idx/warpSize)%2 == 0){
        a = 100.0f;
    }
    else{
        b = 200.0f;
    }
    c[idx] = a+b;
}

__global__ void kernel1(float *c)
{
    float a = 0.0;
    float b = 0.0;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if ((idx/warpSize)%2 == 0){
        a = 100.0f;
    }
    else{
        b = 200.0f;
    }
    c[idx] = a+b;
}

__global__ void kernel2(float *c)
{
    float a = 0.0;
    float b = 0.0;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx%2 == 0){
        a = 100.0f;
    }
    else{
        b = 200.0f;
    }
    c[idx] = a+b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    initDevice(0);
    int size = 64;
    int blocksize = 64;
    int nBytes = sizeof(float)*size;
    float *a_d;
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((float**)&a_d, nBytes));
    dim3 block(blocksize, 1);
    dim3 grid((blocksize-1)/block.x+1, 1);

    wardUp<<<grid, block>>>(a_d);

    float elapsed = 0;
    cudaEvent_t start1, stop1;
    CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&start1));
    CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&stop1));
    CHECK(cudaEventRecord(start1, 0));
    kernel1<<<grid, block>>>(a_d);
    CHECK(cudaEventRecord(stop1, 0));
    CHECK(cudaEventSynchronize(stop1));
    CHECK(cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start1, stop1));
    printf("kernel1 take:%2f ms\n", elapsed);

    float elapsed_1 = 0;
    cudaEvent_t start2, stop2;
    CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&start2));
    CHECK(cudaEventCreate(&stop2));
    CHECK(cudaEventRecord(start2, 0));
    kernel2<<<grid, block>>>(a_d);
    CHECK(cudaEventRecord(stop2, 0));
    CHECK(cudaEventSynchronize(stop2));
    CHECK(cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed_1, start2, stop2));
    printf("kernel2 take:%2f ms\n", elapsed_1);
    
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaEventDestroy(start1);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop1);
    cudaEventDestroy(start2);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop2);
    return 0;
}
```

If my understanding is correct, `kernel1` does not have divergence issue since the `if` branch happens on thread 0-31, the same warp.
`kernel2` will have divergence issue since odd thread and even thread cannot be executed at the same time.
But I observed that `kernel1` is slower than `kernel2`. Why this would happen?

```
Using device: 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
kernel1 take:0.008864 ms
kernel2 take:0.006752 ms
```

I switched to use `cudaEventRecord` to recore the duration but it seems `kernel1` is slower than `kernel2`.

Comment: You are not timing the kernel duration.  You are timing the launch overhead.  Plus this is a very small test case.  And your `grid` is set incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Robert, How should I set the correct grid? Should it be 1-D grid? And how to time the duration of kernel correctly? Is it the correct way to use ```cudaEventRecord``` like this post? https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-measure-total-time-for-cpu-and-gpu/28234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are/were a variety of problems with your approach.  I may not list them all:

- problem size is too small for benchmarking
- compiler optimizations are working against you
- code is too simple; compiler use of predication is mitigating the effects of warp-divergence
- your kernel duration measurement method was flawed
- your creation of the `grid` based on `blocksize` is not sensible (although it happens to be sensible when `size` == `blocksize`).  It should be based on problem `size`, not `blocksize`.

The following code has these issues addressed, and shows approximately a 2x increase in kernel duration, going from the code that does if/then decisions based on warp boundary to code that does that for every other thread:

```
$ cat t1877.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#define CHECK(x) x

__global__ void kernel1(int *c, int y, int z, int l1, int l2)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx&32){
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
          a = a&y; a = a|z;}
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < l2; i++){
          b = b|y; b = b&z;}
    }
    c[idx] = a+b;
}

__global__ void kernel2(int *c, int y, int z, int l1, int l2)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx&1){
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
          a = a&y; a = a|z;}
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < l2; i++){
          b = b|y; b = b&z;}
    }
    c[idx] = a+b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int blocksize = 64;
    int size = blocksize*1048576;
    int nBytes = sizeof(int)*size;
    int *a_d;
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d, nBytes));
    dim3 block(blocksize, 1);
    dim3 grid(size/block.x, 1);

    kernel1<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, 0, 0, 10000, 10000);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    auto start1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    kernel1<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, 0, 0, 10000, 10000);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff1 = end1 - start1;
    printf("kernel1 take:%2f s\n", diff1.count());

    kernel2<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, 0, 0, 10000, 10000);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    auto start2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    kernel2<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, 0, 0, 10000, 10000);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff2 = end2 - start2;
    printf("kernel2 take:%2f s\n", diff2.count());
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1877 t1877.cu -arch=sm_70
$ ./t1877
kernel1 take:0.205650 s
kernel2 take:0.406347 s
$
```

Comment: I have a question. If i record the duration without ```cudaDeviceSynchronize();```. Then it will be the kernel launch overhead, instead of kernel execution time?

Comment: It depends on the overall timing method.  If you use `cudaEvent` based timing, it should not be necessary to use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in the timing region.  If you use ordinary host-based timing like your original example, then without the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (which forces the host thread to wait there until the kernel is done) then you would only be timing the launch overhead.  The topic of how to properly time an asynchronous kernel launch is covered in many other questions.

Comment: Could you please detail about ```compiler optimizations are working against you```? I used cmake to get the perf data. Do you mean that this will impact the performance? So I should use nvcc instead?

Comment: This has nothing to do with cmake vs. nvcc. It has to do with compiler device code generation. It would require that you have substantial understanding on how to do CUDA binary analysis, and related topics. It's covered in many other questions, I wouldn't be able to cover it in comments, and I don't have time to rewrite my answer to provide a tutorial on binary analysis. You may wish to do some research and study.