# Warp divergence in CUDA reduction

Tags: cuda

Following the code in [Harris](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), I have the program attached below. In RTX3060 with cuda 11.4, `rs_base` is 119 GB/s, yet the `rs_1` without warp divergence is only 121 GB/s. The speedup is far less than the result in the slide and the official CUDA samples from [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/reduction) (1.4x speedup in my machine). A similar issue is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68948657/why-the-performance-of-cuda-kernel-w-i-divergence-is-better-than-w-o-divergence). However, I think the problem size and measurement are correct. Could this be the reason for the compilation?

```c
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <stdio.h>
#define CUDA_CHECK(call)                                      \
    do {                                                      \
        cudaError_t err = call;                               \
        if (err != cudaSuccess) {                             \
            std::cerr << "CUDA error: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) \
                      << " at " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ \
                      << std::endl;                           \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                               \
        }                                                     \
    } while (0)
#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

__global__ void rs_base(const float* array, float* res_block, int N){
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float smem[BLOCK_SIZE];   
    smem[tid] = array[i];
    __syncthreads();
    for (unsigned int stride = 1; stride < BLOCK_SIZE; stride*=2){
        if ((tid % (2 * stride)) == 0){
            smem[tid] += smem[tid + stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0) res_block[blockIdx.x] = smem[0];
}

__global__ void rs_1(const float* array, float* res_block, int N){
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float smem[BLOCK_SIZE];   
    smem[tid] = array[i];
    __syncthreads();
    for (unsigned int stride = 1; stride < BLOCK_SIZE; stride*=2){
        int index = 2 * stride * tid;
        if (index < BLOCK_SIZE) {
            smem[index] += smem[index + stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0) res_block[blockIdx.x] = smem[0];
}

void testReduceSumKernelmini(const float* h_in, int N, void (*kernelFunc)(const float*, float*, int), int Niter,
                            dim3 gridSize, dim3 blockSize) {

    float* h_out = (float*)malloc(gridSize.x * sizeof(float));  // Host array for storing results per block
    float* expectedBlockResults = (float*)malloc(gridSize.x * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize.x; i++) {
        float blockSum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < blockSize.x; j++) {
            int index = i * blockSize.x + j;
                blockSum += h_in[index];
        }
        expectedBlockResults[i] = blockSum;
    }

    float* d_in;
    float* d_out;
    unsigned int bytes = N * sizeof(float);
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, bytes));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, gridSize.x * sizeof(float)));   // One float per block
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    
    double reduceTime_ms = 0.0;
    for (int iter = 0; iter < Niter; iter++) {
        auto start1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        kernelFunc <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, d_out, N);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        auto end1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double>diff1 = end1 - start1;
        reduceTime_ms += diff1.count();
    }  
    reduceTime_ms /= Niter;
    double Throughput = 1.0e-9 * ((double)bytes) / reduceTime_ms ;
    printf("Reduction, Throughput = %.4f GB/s, aver Time = %.2f ms \n", Throughput, reduceTime_ms * 1000);
    
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, gridSize.x * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));    
    // Check each block's result
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize.x; i++) {
        if (fabs(h_out[i] - expectedBlockResults[i]) >= 1e-3) {
            printf("Block %d failed! Expected: %f, Got: %f\n", i, expectedBlockResults[i], h_out[i]);
            return;
        }
    }    
    printf("All blocks passed the test!\n");
    free(h_out);
    free(expectedBlockResults);
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_in));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_out));
}


int main() {
    int N=1 << 24; 

    float* h_in = new float[N];
    float result = 0.0f;
    int n_iter = 1000;   

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_in[i] = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    }
    printf("Testing reduceSumKernel...\n");
    dim3 gridSize((N + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 blockSize(BLOCK_SIZE);    

    // warm up
    printf("Testing base...\n");
    testReduceSumKernelmini(h_in, N, rs_base, n_iter, gridSize, blockSize);

    printf("Testing base...\n");
    testReduceSumKernelmini(h_in, N, rs_base, n_iter, gridSize, blockSize);

    printf("Testing rs_1...\n");
    testReduceSumKernelmini(h_in, N, rs_1, n_iter, gridSize, blockSize);
 
    delete[] h_in;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you try with increased or decreased block size?

Comment: Just to clarify: You are saying that your `rs_1` kernel is slower than the equivalent `reduce1` kernel in the CUDA samples?

Comment: @Homer512 First two kernels of CUDA samples in my machine are 70 GB/S, and 105GB/s, separately.  Yet I didn't test these kernels in my own pipeline. I will do this later. I'm just curious why the speedup ratio of my own kernels is low.

Comment: @Sebastian Tried BLOCK_SIZE with 128 and 512. No improvement in my case.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. One possibility is of course that your GPU is more sensitive to bank conflicts than divergence, so divergence isn't the bottleneck. You can check this with CUDA's visual profiler; or simply by comparing with the `reduce2` kernel. But it doesn't explain the difference between `rs_1` and `reduce1`. Oh, BTW: You don't check `i < N` before loading `array[i]`. If your array isn't a multiple of the block size, this will fail

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks for the info. I will try this later. I would like to know why " GPU is more sensitive to bank conflicts than divergence".   Would that be hardware reason or compiler reason?

Comment: Since Volta, Nvidia hardware supports a feature called [independent thread scheduling](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/inside-volta/). I'm fuzzy on the details and how (if at all) it relates to this particular use case but it might lessen the impact of divergence.

Comment: @Homer512 AFAIU it means that a warp will not stop completely, only because some of its threads are blocked. In this case the warp will continue to run others of its threads. Pre-Volta this situation could have led to a deadlock, if threads waited for other threads within the same warp. Independent thread scheduling BTW DOES NOT mean that divergent threads are executed concurrently. The divergent threads still occupy the full resources of 32 threads with some of them being switched to inactive.

Comment: @Sebastian What made me think that it might apply is that mention that "a schedule optimizer which determines how to group active threads from the same warp together into SIMT units". If this allows packing two half-active warps into the same execution unit, it could help. But I guess this code most likely uses predication, not branch divergence, anyway.